# Unable to import ss function from scipy.stats.stats

Tags: python, python-2.7, statistics

Error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 36, in <module>
    from scipy.stats.stats import ss
ImportError: cannot import name ss
```

I tried upgrading scipy and statsmodels but it was still not working.

Comment: I am trying to get p-value using Anderason Darling test available as part of statsmodels(statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.normal_ad(x, axis=0)) but while trying this I keep getting error(AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'diagnostic'). So while trying to import diagnostic(import statsmodels.stats.diagnostic) I get ImportError saying cannot import name ss. I have checked for ss method in scipy.stats.stats and this method exists, not sure why is it unable to import.

Comment: `scipy.stats.stats.ss` has been deprecated since scipy v0.17. If your `statsmodels` is importing from a scipy version >= 0.17, it will show up with that error message. A quick fix is to code your own `ss` function inside the `scipy.stats.stats` source, which was just something like `ss(x) = np.sum(x**2)`.
 See [this](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2424).

Comment: Thanks for the useful info

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I upgraded statsmodels and that fixed the problem, maybe they updated their code to fix the error recently.

Comment: I don't know which version I upgraded from. I have statsmodels 0.8.0, scipy 1.0.1

Comment: Even my issue got fixed after upgrading